# Pass directory into statle.sls

Tags: salt-stack

I am configuring a local Salt setup and I have hit a bit of a wall.
My setup is:
CentOS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
Salt: salt 3000.1

I have a very basic configuration with nothing changed from default in the Master or Minion config.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
/srv/salt/apache/init.sls
/srv/salt/uptodate/common.sls
```

If I run the following:

```
salt '*' state.sls apache Test=true
```

It correctly applies the sls files inside the apache folder.
If I run:

```
salt '*' state.sls uptodate Test=true
```

It returns:

```
minion:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    No matching sls found for 'uptodate' in env 'base'
```

I have no top.sls files configured and if I move common.sls into the apache directory it also does not get applied.

Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The init.sls can be compared to an index.html file on a webserver.
If you want to apply a statefile other than a init.sls you need to add the name of the state file.

This should work for you:

```
salt '*' state.sls uptodate.common test=True
```